# Sort by Number of answers in Unanswered Tab

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Hi All,

When i saw Unanswered questions, i wanted to check all questions with '0' answers first. Is there a way to list unanswered questions, by number of answers it has? If not, do you think it will be good to have it there. I can see only 3 types of listing: Associated with our tags, newest first and by votes on question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always search for questions with zero (0) answers:

> [answers:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers:0)