# Sort unanswered by number of replies

Tags: feature-request, voting, unanswered-questions, sorting, search

A lot of questions, at least on the trinity ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/), [SU](https://superuser.com/), [SF](https://serverfault.com/)), are unanswered (have no upvoted answers).

Scenarios I had in mind:

- Going to a question with many replies, finding a reply worthy of an upvote, upvoting it.
- Editing one of several replies to make it worthy of an upvote, or write a new, worthy, mashup-reply.

It think this would benefit SE, by «clearing away» questions that have answers noone's been bothered to vote on, even though they are good enough, or at least close to being so.

[These](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33068/is-it-possible-to-sort-by-the-number-of-replies) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25077/sort-by-number-of-answers-in-unanswered-tab) are very similar, but both were satisfied with sorting by 0 answers.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get right now is [answers:1 hasaccepted:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a1%20hasaccepted%3a0): note that this won't take answer up-votes into account, and simply orders by timestamp.

A relatively simple enhancement would be a search operator that let you specify *answer up-votes* when searching for questions: so you could do, say, `answervotes:0 answers:1 hasaccepted:0` and get something fairly close to the "unanswered" list, but exclude questions that didn't have answers at all.

Actually *sorting* by number of replies seems less useful to me; I'm not sure that the number of answers actually corresponds to anything particularly important. That said, if it could be implemented as a search operator I would love to see equivalent operators for *other* sort orders: created date, last-modified, votes, views, etc... Currently if you want to specify sort order in a link (as I've done above), you have to use the `tab=` querystring argument - which also changes the default for anyone following the link.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, is it just me, or has it now been fixed?

One can now go Unanswered -> votes, thereby getting "# questions with no upvoted answers".

Seems to sort it by popularity (combo of votes and answers).

I'm too lazy to research if it's been done, but if this is indeed the case: This question can be marked as `status-completed`, and thanks for implementing!